# Why wasn't this seemingly unfriendly/unkind comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I flagged the following [comment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24550/can-changing-ones-address-within-the-same-uscis-field-office-delay-ones-us-nat#comment40820_24550) as unfriendly/unkind, and the flag got declined. Wasn't this comment calling the OP a troll and asking them to see a therapist unfriendly/unkind?

> No, they don't. They can share their experiences, anecdotal evidence, but they don't *know* how that would reflect on *your* case. I think you should handle your anxiety about your immigration process in ways other than trolling this forum. There are professional options available, lawyers and therapists alike. [littleadv](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/136/littleadv) [15 hours ago](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24550/can-changing-ones-address-within-the-same-uscis-field-office-delay-ones-us-nat#comment40820_24550)

[image]

The same happened for this comment:

> Have you posted an answer just to get upvotes, as with all the rest of your self-answered nuisance questions? [littleadv](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/136/littleadv) [11 hours ago](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24550/can-changing-ones-address-within-the-same-uscis-field-office-delay-ones-us-nat#comment40833_24551)

Answer (score 4):

I declined that flag because I don't want to get involved in your ongoing fighting with littleadv. You post an awful lot of stuff about naturalising to the USA, and he posts the occasional comment on your posts. You complain about him, and he complains about you.

I can see both sides to this argument, and won't be drawn into taking a side. I have been declining both of your flags, and will continue to do so until one of you crosses a line (which I have not drawn yet).

You only see the flags you raised that I declined. You don't see the flags I declined from littleadv. Don't assume bias unless you have evidence of such.

In an ideal world, you would panic less about your ongoing naturalisation process, and would just let it work its way through without asking everyone around you what individual things mean, and littleadv would refrain from commenting on your posts.

Comment: I'm not fighting anyone, just pointing out some obviously unfriendly language.